# ValueError: Shapes (None, 64) and (None, 2365) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, chatbot

i'm creating a general chat-bot with a Recurrent Neural Network using Tensorflow, i have a data that are questions and answers ì, each questions is inside tuple that pair with the answers also in a tuple like:

```
questions = (("How are you?"), ("Who are you?"))
answers = (("I'm fine, thank you"), ("I'm Mr. Nobody"))
```

this data i've splitted using train-test_split from sklearn.model_selection, and now i have train_x, test_y, train_y, test_y; This is the code:

```
self.train_x, self.test_x, self.train_y, self.test_y = train_test_split(
            self.questions, self.answers, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Now i have a function `preprocess_data()` that convert the text to a sequence of integer and after, pad this sequences, here is the code:

```
def preprocess_data(self):
    # Tokenize texts
    t = Tokenizer()
    t.fit_on_texts(self.train_x)

    # Convert text to sequences of integers
    train_questions = t.texts_to_sequences(self.train_x)
    test_questions = t.texts_to_sequences(self.test_x)

    train_answers = t.texts_to_sequences(self.train_y)
    test_answers = t.texts_to_sequences(self.test_y)
        
    # Pad sequences
    self.train_x = pad_sequences(train_questions, maxlen=self.max_sequences_length)
    self.test_x = pad_sequences(test_questions, maxlen=self.max_sequences_length)

    self.train_y = pad_sequences(train_answers, maxlen=self.max_sequences_length)
    self.test_y = pad_sequences(test_answers, maxlen=self.max_sequences_length)
```

And there is the architecture of the RNN:

```
def build_model(self):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 128, input_length=self.max_sequences_length))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.SimpleRNN(64, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(self.vocabulary), activation="sigmoid"))

    return model
```

And then with the function `train_model()` i compile and fit the model:

```
def train_model():
     self.preprocess_data()
     model = self.build_model()

     model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
     model.fit(self.train_x, self.train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

But when i run the program for train the neural network i get this error `ValueError: Shapes (None, 64) and (None, 2365) are incompatible`. Is there some step I'm missing or did I do some process that I shouldn't have? someone can help me, I'm new in this field.

There are the shapes of the data:

```
train_x shape: (2980, 64)
train_y shape: (2980, 64)
test_x shape: (745, 64)
test_y shape: (745, 64)
```

I wanted to try to reshape my data, but i don't know what shapes put.

whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/matte/Coding/projects/ai-projects/general-chatbot/chatbot.py", line 183, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/matte/Coding/projects/ai-projects/general-chatbot/chatbot.py", line 138, in main
    neural_network.train_model()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/matte/Coding/projects/ai-projects/general-chatbot/chatbot.py", line 115, in train_model
    model.fit(self.train_x, self.train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
  File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file6oeizk3o.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1984, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/home/breadpit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5559, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 64) and (None, 64, 2365) are incompatible
```

Comment: post the complete stacktrace, where are you getting the ValueError

Comment: @darthbaba Do you mean the whole error right? if so, i've posted it

Comment: remove the dropout layer after embedding

Comment: @darthbaba alright done, still shows the error, but now it shows "ValueError: Shapes (None, 64) and (None, 64, 2365) are incompatible"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that 2365 is the `len(self.vocabulary)`
but your ground_truth is 63+1, may be you should one-hot the ground-truth to 2365，this is the steps of the preprocess you forget to finish.
`model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(self.vocabulary), activation="sigmoid"))`
this line in model definition, it is using for classification, so you should check this line with "self.train_y" and predict. 
`model.fit(self.train_x, self.train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=32)`

you can refer these links by tensorflow
[keras text_classification_from_scratch](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/)

[keras using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html)

It looks like one-hot is required in classification
`labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))`

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))
print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', labels.shape)

# split the data into a training set and a validation set
indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
labels = labels[indices]
nb_validation_samples = int(VALIDATION_SPLIT * data.shape[0])

x_train = data[:-nb_validation_samples]
y_train = labels[:-nb_validation_samples]
x_val = data[-nb_validation_samples:]
y_val = labels[-nb_validation_samples:]
```